# representation of values (x,y) vs x._1,y._1

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to spark using scala and very much confused by the notations (x,y) in some scenarios and x._1, y._1. Especially when they are used one over the other in spark transformations

could someone explain is there a specific rule of thumb for when to use each of these syntaxes

Comment: Use `(x,y)` with proper naming as it's easier to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Basically there are 2 ways to access a tuple parameter in anonymous function. They're functionally equivalent, use whatever method you prefer.

1. Through the attributes `_1`, `_2`,...
2. Through pattern matching into variable with meaningful name

   ```
   val tuples = Array((1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4))

   // Attributes
   tuples.foreach { t => 
     println(s"${t._1} ${t._2}")
   }

   // Pattern matching
   tuples.foreach { t =>
     t match {
       case (first, second) =>
         println(s"$first $second")
     }
   }

   // Pattern matching can also written as
   tuples.foreach { case (first, second) =>
       println(s"$first $second")
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

The notation `(x, y)` is a **tuple** of 2 elements, `x` and `y`. There are different ways to get access to the individual values in a tuple. You can use the `._1`, `._2` notation to get at the elements:

```
val tup = (3, "Hello")    // A tuple with two elements

val number = tup._1       // Gets the first element (3) from the tuple
val text = tup._2         // Gets the second element ("Hello") from the tuple
```

You can also use pattern matching. One way to extract the two values is like this:

```
val (number, text) = tup
```

Unlike a collection (for example, a `List`) a tuple has a fixed number of values (it's not always exactly two values) and the values can have different types (such as an `Int` and a `String` in the example above).

There are many tutorials about Scala tuples, for example: [Scala tuple examples and syntax](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-tuple-examples-syntax).